# Problemas em uma pilha cujas posições devem ser selecionadas? ( warning: implicit declaration e warning: pointer from integer)

Tags: c, struct, estrutura-de-dados, stack, warnings

Olá, hoje venho trazendo aqui uma questão relativa a estruturas de dados que certamente pode acrescentar no entendimento de todos os envovilidos. Trata-se de uma questão de manipulação de pilha onde através do ato de percorrer esta pilha tenta-se formar "diamantes" representados por "<" e ">" formando "<>" enquanto se ignora "." que aqui representa cascalho.

O problema é que estou tendo diversos problemas de incompatibilidade sempre que trabalho neste tema então acredito estar fazendo algo fundamentalmente errado. Este será meu post definitivo sobre o tema e talvez por aqui eu consiga sanar as mais diversas dúvidas relacionadas

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
struct mine{
char mining[1000];
int num_minings;
int top;
int left_side, right_side, full_diamond;
}mine;


void mining_cases(struct mine mine){
printf("Digite o numero de mineracoes/n");
scanf("/p%d" &mine.num_minings);
int aux = mine.num_minings;
    while(aux != NULL){
        miner(mine.mining);
        aux -=1;
}
void miner(struct mine mine){
    printf("iniciando minerador.../n");
    scanf("%c",&mine.mining);
    while( mine.mining!= "\0"){
        if(mine.mining == "<"){
            ++mine.left_side;
        }
         if(mine.mining == ">"){
            ++mine.right_side;
        }
        if (mine.left_side == mine.right_side){
            mine.full_diamond = mine.right_side;
        }
         if (mine.left_side != mine.right_side && mine.right_side > mine.left_side){
            mine.full_diamond -= (mine.right_side - mine.left_side);
        }
        if (mine.left_side != mine.right_side && mine.left_side > mine.right_side){
            mine.full_diamond -= (mine.left_side - mine.right_side);
        }

}

void main(struct mine mine){
mining_cases(struct mine mine);

}
```

Eis a lista de erros que estou tendo:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
||In function 'mining_cases':|
|14|error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'int')|
|16|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|
|17|warning: implicit declaration of function 'miner' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
||In function 'main':|
|43|error: expected expression before 'struct'|
|In function 'miner':|
|45|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input|
|In function 'mining_cases':|
|45|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Sem entrar nos aspectos de seu código mas atendo-se ao conceito de "pilha", em uma pilha você só tem acesso ao topo da pilha e as operações permitidas são acrescentar um elemento na pilha (push) e retirar o elemento topo da pilha (pop). Se você considera que está tratando seu array mining como uma pilha então está errado.

Comment: Quanto a seu código para operar com strings você tem que utilizar as funções de <string.h>. Isto: `scanf("%c",&mine.mining);` não tem sentido já que `mining` é um array de caracteres e não um único caractere. Utilize ou `scanf("%s", mine.mining);` ou `scanf("%c",&mine.mining[i]);`, assim como `if(mine.mining[i] == '<'){` ou a função `strcmp`. Estude sobre arrays e ponteiros.